# Реализация компьютера в игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

В ходе разработки игры столкнулся с задачей реализации не то чтобы компьютера, а внутриигровой операционной системы. Это не главная задача игры, а её часть, через компьютер будут производиться какие-то сделки или же запускаться полезные для игрока программы, не в этом суть. Суть в реализации - нужна отрисовка в реалтайме на мониторе всего происходящего в системе, а по нажатию кнопки взаимодействие "входить" в систему, соответственно интерактировать с ней. Пробовал через канвас в world space переносить в оверлей, но возникают проблемы с размерами самого канваса после переноса. Как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. тебе нужно создать плейн на экране монитора
2. применить на него материал с Render Texture https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html
3. Рендерить на нем картинку с другой камеры (по той же линке описано)
4. Что бы удобно взаимодействовать с компьютером советую полностью переключатся на вид из этой другой камеры

А на другой камере должен отрисовыватся уже канвас.